# template specialization for type OR template parameter

Tags: templates, c++11, template-specialization

I have a class that enumerates the member symbols of a type or categories of types for templated types.  I use a macro to overcome the C++ symbol shortcomings to abstract the symbols of a type to use orthogonally.  Because I have direct access to the symbol abstraction, the nature of the object being operated on is mostly irrelevant.

Example usage is:

```
struct MyNonTemplatedStruct
  { int Num; float FloatNum; };

template< typename SomeType >
struct MyTemplatedStruct
  { int Count; SomeType Object;  };


mDeclareRTTI_Type( MyNonTemplatedStruct, Num, FloatNum );

mDeclareRTTI_Type( MyTemplatedStruct, Count, Object );

MyRTTClass<MyNonTemplatedStruct> RTTI_N;

MyRTTClass<MyTemplatedStruct> RTTI_T;

cout << RTTI_N.IDName(0);              // "Num"
cout << RTTI_T.IDName(RTTI_T.Object);  // "Object"

typename RTTI_N::ThisType StackMyNonTemplatedStruct;

auto HeapMyTemplatedStruct = RTTI_T.New<float>();
```

currently I am having to have 2 versions of my mDeclareRTTI_Type() / mDeclareRTTI_Type_Templated_Version() because I can't determine a way to declare
a template that can accommodate either specialization.

```
template<...> //unrestricted by number, typename or non-type
MyRTTIClass {};

template< typename T>
template<> MyRTTIClass<T> {};

template< template<typename...> class Tmpl >
template<> MyRTTIClass<Tmpl> {};
```

The same difficulty repeats for the template template parameter parameters.  i.e a template type or non-type parameter for Tmpl<> requires a signature for each combination.  My work-around for that is to restrict those parameters to typename...

Does anyone know of a system of wrappers that can overcome either or both of those related limitations?

This is my first question on stack overflow, so I hope I have provided enough information for context of the what and why components of the question.  Additionally, the boost library is too large to be considered, but if a library has a solution, I can try to extract it from it if I know where it solves it.

Thanks

Comment: I should probably clarify that mDeclareRTTI_Type(classname,member1,...) is a macro that declares a specialization for MyRTTClass.  Internally it uses a macro for each to create serialization, visitor interface, tuple-like representation and index mapping of members on a per symbol basis.  I thought including it's details would obfuscate the problem I'm having so I left them out.

Comment: Are you aware of the [adapters](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted.html) supplied by boost's fusion library?  They seem to be in the same problem space you are working in... namely adapting a type to a sequence of members at compile time.  It will probably be helpful to look at the interface the library provides to adapt structures and model yours after that.  You may be able to avoid the infinite regress you described this way.  And as you probably know, you are free to download the source code from boost's website.

Comment: Here's an idea: you may able to wrap / adapt all non-template types / values in a template which carries all the necessary information about the type / value.  This way you don't need a template which accommodates both template and non-template types.  I.E. You would only need `mDeclareRTTI_Type_Templated_Version()`.  Hopefully I understand your problem and this wasn't total nonsense!

Comment: @dog jones  Thanks, the adapters do indeed have a treatment for templates and I am checking it out.  It appears very explicit, requiring the user to recreate the template signature manually, just as it requires the user to add type information for each member.  My approach has solved the problem of manually requiring type information to be manually replicated by the user.  Since the information is already present implicitly, I am trying to expose an explicit version of it so I can use the same automatic approach to template signatures.

Comment: @dog jones.  Yeah, I am leaning toward treating everything as a template with a special NULL_TEMPLATE, argument to be passed when it is not actually a template.  There is a large advantage to being able to treat things uniformly.  I think I even have a macro trick that can detect if NULL_TEMPLATE is passed and conditionally respond during macro evaluation if it is.

Comment: /* map a unique type to each template signature */
struct Type_Atomic{};
struct Type_Tmpl_Null{};
struct Type_Tmpl_Tn{};
struct Type_Tmpl_I_Tn{};
//...etc...


/* use parameter deduction with overloaded functions to apply the mapping */ 
template< typename Tn > Type_Atomic test_if_template( Tn XX) {  };

template< template<typename...> class TT_Tn, typename... Tn > Type_Tmpl_Tn test_if_template(TT_Tn<Tn...> XX) {  };

template<  template<int, typename...> class TT_Tn, int I, typename... Tn> Type_Tmpl_I_Tn test_if_template(TT_Tn<I, Tn...> XX) {  };

//...etc...

Comment: hmm, no idea how to format that, or why it only lets me use a few characters.  Anyway, that is an approach I came up with that allows a type to be tested to determine if it is a composited template or just a regular non-template.  It also allows me to classify the different signatures of a template and map each signature to a unique type.

Comment: this is an example of usage: /* some template signature examples to test */
struct TypeToTest0{};
template< typename...Tn> struct TypeToTest1{};
template< int I, typename...Tn> struct TypeToTest2{};

/* retrieve the signature mapped type from the examples */
decltype(test_if_template(TypeToTest0())) TT0;
decltype(test_if_template(TypeToTest1<>())) TT1;
decltype(test_if_template(TypeToTest2<1>())) TT2;

Comment: I am still hunting around for how to retrieve the actual type of non type parameters (i.e. int, enum, pointer, etc.) because it seems impossible to create a general signature for them without either knowing all non types in advance or explicitly parameterizing the type of non-type.  Casting them to raw bits of sufficient size will probably work to a degree, but enum A with a value of '1' would then be directly equivalent to enum B with a value of '1' and the ambiguity makes it only very conditionally useful.

Comment: Check out [boost::mpl::integral_c](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/integral-c.html).  Its a template which accepts a typename and a value of type typename.  The body of the template then exposes the typename and the constant value.  You can 'typify' values in this way. You should be passing around these typified values rather than the raw, non-type values themselves.